# Default value for a List in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a Realm model class as below.

```
class Trip: Object {
    dynamic var userId: String = ""
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var startTimestamp: Int64 = 0
    dynamic var endTimestamp: Int64 = 0
    let bumpLocations = List<BumpLocation>()
    let brakeLocations = List<BrakeLocation>()
    dynamic var distance: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var calories: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var averageSpeed: Double = 0.0
}
```

I create objects of this like this.

```
let tripData: [String: Any] = [
    "userId": self.trip!.userId,
    "id": self.trip!.id,
    "startTimestamp": self.trip!.startTimestamp,
    "endTimestamp": self.trip!.endTimestamp,
    "distance": self.trip!.distance,
    "calories": self.trip!.calories,
    "averageSpeed": self.trip!.averageSpeed
]
realm.create(Trip.self, value: tripData, update: true)
```

At the time of creating these objects, there are no values to be added to the properties `bumpLocations` and `brakeLocations`. So I need to add default values for these fields, right?

What's the default value for properties of type `List`?

I get a crash at `realm.create`. I think this is because the `create` function expects all the properties of the model class to be listed in the dictionary the same way as it is specified in the class. And since it's missing `bumpLocations` and `brakeLocations`, it messes up the order the class is created from the value dictionary? As in it adds the value of the `distance` field to the `bumpLocations` property and `calories` value to the `brakeLocations` property and so on.

The crash reports I got.

[Report #1](https://codepaste.net/xe1ff5)

[Report 2](https://codepaste.net/hjkcjb)

Got this [output](https://codepaste.net/j4bge8) in the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to add a default values for the two lists, since they already have the default value of an empty List defined in your Realm object class definition.

In the line `let bumpLocations = List<BumpLocation>()` the parentheses create are the shorthand notation for calling an init method without any input arguments, so this line actually assigns an empty `List` to the `bumpLocations` variable.

```
class Trip: Object {
    ...
    let bumpLocations = List<BumpLocation>()
    let brakeLocations = List<BrakeLocation>()
}
```

Below code is perfectly valid.

```
let tripData: [String: Any] = [
    "userId": self.trip!.userId,
    "id": self.trip!.id,
    "startTimestamp": self.trip!.startTimestamp,
    "endTimestamp": self.trip!.endTimestamp,
    "distance": self.trip!.distance,
    "calories": self.trip!.calories,
    "averageSpeed": self.trip!.averageSpeed,
]
try! realm.write {
    realm.create(Trip.self, value: tripData)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. However, I'm getting a crash at `realm.create`. I updated the question with what I believe is the cause. I also changed the sample code I added above a little to better illustrate the issue.

Comment: Your reasoning is wrong. As I have already explained in my answer, those values have a default value, so you don't need to specify a value in the initializer. The crash most probably happens due to `self.trip` being `nil`, but without seeing more code I cannot tell that for sure.

Comment: I added the crash reports I got if that's any help.

Comment: Check my updated code, with dummy data instead of `self.trip`, the code works perfectly, I have tested it. You need to make all changes to Realm inside a write transaction and you can only update objects that have primary keys.